# How can i remover this autocomplete in my text box?

Tags: html

I have this HTML code, and I need to remove a autocomplete that appears when I text something.

```
<div class="col-sm-9 form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email Profissional:
        <small id="helpBlock" class="text-secondary">
            <a class="not-active text-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Escreva o seu email profissional, caso não tenha email-profissional como por exemplo
        usa email com serviço @gmail, @hotmail entre outros... não exite e crie um em meros
        segundos.">
            <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> + info
            </a>
        </small>
    </label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control form-way" data-name="email" placeholder="Exemplo: info@<?= $pageData['name'] ?>.pt" value="<?= $pageData['email'] ?>">
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try `autocomplete="off"`?

Comment: what's the problem, and what exactly are you hoping someone can help you with?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add `autocomplete="off"` to your input field:

```
<div class="col-sm-9 form-group">
  <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email Profissional:
    <small id="helpBlock" class="text-secondary">
      <a class="not-active text-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" 
          data-placement="right" 
          title="Escreva o seu email profissional, caso não tenha email-profissional como por exemplo usa email com serviço @gmail, @hotmail entre outros... não exite e crie um em meros segundos.">
        <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
        + info
      </a>
    </small>
  </label>
  <input autocomplete="off" type="email"
     name="email" id="email" class="form-control form-way" 
     data-name="email" placeholder="Exemplo: info@<?= $pageData['name'] ?>.pt" value="<?= $pageData['email'] ?>">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your information, you did try with autocomplete="off", If still have problem then you can use autocomplete="user-email"